# How can I require admin login on a Django site only if a certain environment variable is set?

Tags: django, django-authentication, staging

I have two AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments serving content using the same Django web server. One of them is a staging site (i.e. for development/testing purposes) and one of them is the production website. On the staging site, features that normally require payment are free to use in order to simplify testing and development. I want to avoid having users stumble upon this staging site and gaining free access to features that normally require payment.

To prevent this, I would like to require staff login for *all* of the views, but only on the staging site. I have an environment variable that gets checked in `settings.py` which determines whether or not the server is running in the staging or production environment. Is there some elegant/clean way of accomplishing this by checking that environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/) that checks for this condition to the MIDDLEWARE settings variable if the environment variable says you're on staging.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy, bro!
Just use conditions in your `urls.py` file

```
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [ YOU REGULAR URLS HERE ]

if settings.SPECIFIC_VALUE:
    urlpatterns = [
        ADDITIONAL URLS WHICH WILL BE AVAILABLE IF SPECIFIC VALUE IS ON
    ] + urlpatterns
```